# How to Warm up the Server Cache without using sitemap?

Tags: linux, shell-script, webserver, cache

I need to write a script which Warm up the Application Cache with the website Pages when my server restarts so that when a User visits the website, the pages will be served from Cache leading to a better response time.

Can someone help me writing a script to warm up the Cache with those pages using a bash script please?
I have been thinking of using *wget* command to load the URL but not sure if that is the correct approach? I have come up to the below code till now.
Any help is appreciated.

`#!/bin/bash
input="/home/testadmin/url.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
        echo Refreshing $line
        wget --no-check-certificate --no-cache "$line"
        #time wget -pq --no-check-certificate --no-cache --delete-after "$line"
        #curl -s -w %{time_total}\\n -o /dev/null "$line"
  done < "$input"`

Comment: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com might have more webserver experts, but if you're asking how to write a script on a UNIX/Linux system, you're on-topic here. From the sounds of the current question, it seems your question is more around whether retrieving those URLs would appropriately load the cache; is that correct?

Comment: Hi Jeff, yes so this is what I have created till now. My requirement is basically to Warm up or load the server cache when the server restarts so that Pages can be served quickly. This is what I have written till now. Is that correct?

#!/bin/bash
input="/home/testadmin/url.txt"
while IFS= read -r line
do
        echo Refreshing $line
        wget --no-check-certificate --no-cache "$line"
        #time wget -pq --no-check-certificate --no-cache --delete-after "$line"
        curl -s -w %{time_total}\\n -o /dev/null "$line"
  done < "$input"

Comment: Comments, as you've seen, have limited formatting; please edit your current script into your question so that Answerers know where you're starting from. Thank you!

Comment: The place to [edit your question is here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/529856/edit)

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I have edited my question with the Code